# How request chat response with openai-node?

Tags: node.js, openai-api

I'm using the [node package](https://github.com/openai/openai-node), trying to get it to answer generic question with title + body (note: not Stack Overflow questions). Though I can't see how I'm supposed to do a "chat" request to GPT3. The closest I found is completion:

```
const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
    model: 'text-davinci-003',
    prompt: `Please provide an answer to the question below.\n#${question.title}\n${question.text}`,
    temperature: 0.9
});
```

However, like expected this will not give an answer rather extend the question with an extra sentence or so. How can I call the API to do something like https://chat.openai.com/chat ? There my question will get a nice multiline answer, but I can't understand how to replicate it using their API.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `createCompletion` is the method you are looking for, but you need to tweak it a bit. Try this:

```
const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
    model: 'text-davinci-003',
    prompt: `Please provide an answer to the question below.\n#${question.title}\n${question.text}`,
    temperature: 0,
    max_tokens: 500,
    top_p: 1,
    frequency_penalty: 0.0,
    presence_penalty: 0.0
});
```

#### Sample question

> I have an array of numbers, lets say
>
> const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] How can I make a method chunk to
> split it up into chunks of certain length? Something like:
>
> const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] const chunks = chunk(numbers, 3)
> // [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]] How can I do that?

#### Sample answer

> You can use the `Array.prototype.slice()` method to create a chunk
> algorithm in JavaScript. The `slice()` method takes two arguments, the
> starting index and the ending index, and returns a new array
> containing the elements from the original array between the two
> indices.
>
> ```
> For example, to create a chunk algorithm that splits an array into chunks of a certain length, you could use a `for` loop to iterate over
> ```
>
> the array and use the `slice()` method to create a new array
> containing the elements from the original array between the two
> indices.
>
> ````
> Here is an example of a chunk algorithm in JavaScript:
>
> ```js
> function chunk(arr, size) {
>   const chunked = [];
>   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) {
>     chunked.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));
>   }
>   return chunked;
> }
>
> const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
> const chunks = chunk(numbers, 3)
> // [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
> ```
> ````